# Converting argv arguments to double

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have created a .srv file in Ros. Which is structured as follows.

```
float64 a
float64 a
---
bool response
```

Now I try to read the chars which are in the `argv` as `float`.
My output is always the same no matter which values I pass.
Output:

```
check Numbers
a: 94290532670520
b: 0
```

Where is my mistake?
Thanks in advance.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  if (argc != 3) {
      RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "usage: add_two_ints_client theta x");
      return 1;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("add_two_ints_client");
  rclcpp::Client<robot_control::srv::RobotControl>::SharedPtr client =
    node->create_client<robot_control::srv::RobotControl>("add_two_ints");

  auto request = std::make_shared<robot_control::srv::RobotControl::Request>();  
  request->theta = std::atof(argv[0]);
  request->x = std::atof(argv[1]);

//  request->theta = std::atoll(argv[1]);
//  request->x = std::atoll(argv[2]);


  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "check Numbers\na: %ld" " b: %ld",
                request->theta, request->x);
```

Comment: `argv[0]` is program name

Comment: I mean float not double.

Comment: Use %f instead of %ld

Comment: *My output is always the same* -- You are not using a debugger?  The very first error should have been obvious if you are using a debugger (the `argv[0]` error), long before any output would have been displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `argv[0]` is the program name; you probably meant `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.
2. Your log output is wrong; `%ld` means `long int`, not `float` or `double`. Try `%f`.